# non-viral open-source implementations of mktime?

Tags: c, time, embedded

I'm working on microcontroller w/ a primitive standard library, and I need to convert a calendar time structure to a time-offset-from-epoch and back, ala [`struct tm`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/tm/) <-> `time_t`. There's no built-in function available to do this.

Could anyone refer me to a decent implementation which is open-source licensed, usable in proprietary software? (i.e. non-LGPL/GPL)

I can probably write one on my own but figured I should see if I can get a head start.

Comment: Presumably BSD must implement this?

Comment: What does "non-viaral" mean in this context?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was just thinking that BSDs use their own `libc` when Neil Butterworth commented. Look in `lib/libc/stdtime/localtime.c` for `mktime` and `time1`. You should be able to rip `time1` without problems.

Here it is: **[src/lib/libc/stdtime/Attic/localtime.c](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/cvsweb.cgi/src/lib/libc/stdtime/Attic/localtime.c)**

Comment: could you add a link to their source? if it looks good, I'll accept.

Answer (score 4):

[Newlib](http://www.sourceware.org/newlib/) is a non-GPL implementation of the standard library intended for embedded devices. It contains a [`mktime`](http://www.sourceware.org/newlib/libc.html#index-mktime-450) call. Some of the files within are GPL, however, so be careful which ones you utilize ([full licensing terms](http://www.sourceware.org/newlib/COPYING.NEWLIB)).

I'm a big proponent in embedded work of not reinventing the standard library. You'll undoubtedly need more of it than just `mktime`, so it might be worth looking into.

Comment: That's not quite right. There are no GPL components in newlib, only some LGPL.

Comment: mktime.c new location: https://www.sourceware.org/git/?p=newlib-cygwin.git;a=blob;f=newlib/libc/time/mktime.c